# "Where am I and my sister?" or "Where are I and my sister?"

Tags: questions, singular-vs-plural, coordination

Which questions is correct:

1. "Where **am** I and my sister?"

   or
2. "Where **are** I and my sister?"

Comment: I'd use "Where are my sister and I?" Arguing about how many grammarians find either of the others grammatically acceptable ignores the virtual need for idiomaticity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner)

Comment: @Edwin: *My* need for idiomaticity requires me to forget about ***I*** and ask *Where are **me** and my sister?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Think about it:

My sister and I are going to the store.

My sister and I are now at the store.

My sister and I are where?

Where are my sister and I?

Don't semantically muddle the issue by relocating "I" before "sister" in order to lean on the seeming rightness of "I am."  However you decide to say it, though, "my sister and I" or the more egomaniacal "I and my sister," it doesn't change the fact that it calls for the first-person plural conjugation of the verb "to be," also known as the "we" conjugation.

Comment: Or, better yet, just ask: "Where are we?"

Comment: @Mari-Lou A : Yes, absolutely.  That is what any natural speaker would say.

Comment: For the prurpose of my conversation I cannot ask "where are we?"

Comment: @Peter : That doesn't change the fact.  The same conjugation applies whether you say "we" or "my sister and I."  They are both second-person plural.  The answer remains "are."

Comment: @Peter : Make no mistake, the subject of the sentence is "my sister and I," not "where."  This is an example of inversion.  We invert the subject and the verb when forming questions.  If we were not to use inversion, it would be "Where my sister and I are?"  But we do use inversion, so we say, "Where are my sister and I?"

Comment: '... it doesn't change the fact that it calls for the first-person plural conjugation of the verb "to be,"...' needs supporting evidence. I'd say 'Where are I and my sister?' is at best close to unacceptable, which trumps the 'this needs plural agreement' argument. // There are examples showing that 'the obvious answer' is not always correct, such as 'It's us' and 'More than one person was unhappy'. 'Think about it' is not safe here.

Answer (score 0):

my sister and I are where?

I and my sister are where?

would be natural and gramatic ways of asking the question, which brings you to rearranging into another semantically correct form of the question:

where are my sister and I?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the issue with:

> Where are we, my sister and I?